# How to animate array values in svelte with tweened store?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have a writable store with following data

```
   let array= writable({
                          skills: [{
                                    id: 1,
                                    name: "Wordpress",
                                    knowledge: 0.9
                                   }, 
                                   {
                                    id: 2,
                                    name: "Js",
                                    knowledge: 0.8
                                     } ]
                      })
```

I want to animate progress bar according to KNOWLEDGE, im accessing knowledge in {#each } loop, but bar is not animated, beacause i have to pass tweened store object and set it value. So how to animate bar ? how to pass knowledge value in to tweened object set() method in loop ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each record in the array needs a corresponding `tweened()` store. You can create a component to do this for you.

1. Create a component that wraps `<progress/>` and has a `tweened()` store:

```html
<!-- SkillProgress.svelte -->
<script>
    import {tweened} from 'svelte/motion'

    export let value = 0

    const progress = tweened(0)

    progress.set(value)
</script>

<progress value={$progress}/>
```

2. In `App.svelte`, bind a `<SkillProgress/>` component for each skill record:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import SkillProgress from './SkillProgress.svelte'
  import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

  const skills = writable([{
            id: 1,
            name: "Wordpress",
            knowledge: 0.9
        }, 
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Js",
            knowledge: 0.8
        }])
</script>

<ul>
    {#each $array.skills as skill}
        <li>
            {skill.name}
            <SkillProgress value={skill.knowledge}/>
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to the answer by joshnuss above.

SkillProgress.svelte needs one change:

progress.set(value)
*should be*
$: progress.set(value)