# Is it possible to get the state of a svelte tweened motion?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, while something is moving from one tweened state to another, I want to further highlight the motion , but want to end up in the same state as before.

Using part of the example from the svelte tutorial:

```html
<script>
    const progress = tweened(0, {
        duration: 400,
        easing: cubicOut
    });
</script>

<progress value={$progress}></progress>

<button on:click="{() => progress.set(0.25)}">
    25%
</button>

<button on:click="{() => progress.set(0.5)}">
    50%
</button>
```

During the 400ms duration, I want to display the progress bar in a different color. So if it is usually blue, I want it to be red for the entire 400ms and then go back to its original color.

For this I would simply need to know if `progress` is currently "tweening" (sorry, not sure what the word here is) or not. So for example

```html
<progress value={$progress} class:tweening={progress.tweening === true}></progress>

<style>
.tweening {
  /* my styles I want to apply while tweening */
}
</style>
```

Is this possible without adding lots of complexity (e.g. not manually checking that the HTML value is changing every few ms)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Svelte [tweened](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-motion-tweened) function returns basic svelte store.

You can get the state while it's animating using `progress.subscribe(console.log)`. In the console you will see one number only per log. Yes, that's the only data you can read.

But (from [svelte.dev/tutorial/tweened](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tweened))

> The `set` and `update` methods both return a promise that resolves when the tween completes.

So you can just wait until promise resolves and then change the color of your progressbar back to the "normal" one.

Code example:

```js
let tweening = false;
async function setProgress(v: number) {
    tweening = true;
    await progress.set(v)
    tweening = false;
}
```

Or [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fcd8b35e6d754887b0493057502fe4c1?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Thanks. I think the derived store is probably the closest to what I would like to achieve. Optimally it is as closely coupled to the actual tweened values as possible, so while there are other ways to do it (e.g. the setTimeout one), it feels less clean to me. 

I ll wait to accept your answer for now in case someone posts a more direct solution.

Comment: I am so sorry for the inconvience. I came up with stupid solution when there is much better one :) I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh yeah that looks pretty straight forward, thank you! I checked the docs, but did not come to this solution, but now it makes a lot of sense :).

Comment: It goes beyond my initial question, but any idea how I could do this for a tweened array where I want to know for each value in the array whether it is currently animating?

Comment: That's some rocket science here :) You can't just track array of tweeneds. First thing that comes to my mind is second array with statuses and third array with setters, but that sound like bs. Keep in mind that you don't need to use svelte native `tweened`. It's just a javascript functions. Take a look at the source code, try to fork it and make it more accessible for your needs.

Comment: After searching a bit more, the solution to this question turned out to be the answer. That way I can use your solution for single values inside the component
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218304/how-to-animate-array-values-in-svelte-with-tweened-store